# BULK API : Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

Using Elasticsearch 5.5,getting the following error while posting this bulk request, unable to figure out what is wrong with the request.

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
```

POST http://localhost:9200/access_log_index/access_log/_bulk

```
{ "index":{ "_id":11} }
{  
   "id":11,
   "tenant_id":682,
   "tenant_name":"kcc",
   "user.user_name":"k0772251",
   "access_date":"20170821",
   "access_time":"02:41:44.123+01:30",
   "operation_type":"launch_service",
   "remote_host":"qlsso.quicklaunchsso.com",
   "user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; LGLS775 Build/NRD90U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36",
   "browser":"",
   "device":"",
   "application.application_id":1846,
   "application.application_name":"Desire2Learn",
   "geoip.ip":"192.95.18.163",
   "geoip.country_code":"US",
   "geoip.country_name":"United States",
   "geoip.region_code":"NJ",
   "geoip.region_name":"New Jersey",
   "geoip.city":"Newark",
   "geoip.zip_code":7102,
   "geoip.time_zone":"America/New_York",
   "geoip.latitude":40.7355,
   "geoip.longitude":-74.1741,
   "geoip.metro_code":501
}
{ "index":{"_id":12} }
{  
   "id":12,
   "tenant_id":682,
   "tenant_name":"kcc",
   "user.user_name":"k0772251",
   "access_date":"20170821",
   "access_time":"02:50:44.123+01:30",
   "operation_type":"launch_service",
   "remote_host":"qlsso.quicklaunchsso.com",
   "user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; LGLS775 Build/NRD90U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36",
   "browser":"",
   "device":"",
   "application.application_id":2341,
   "application.application_name":"Gmail",
   "geoip.ip":"192.95.18.163",
   "geoip.country_code":"US",
   "geoip.country_name":"United States",
   "geoip.region_code":"NJ",
   "geoip.region_name":"New Jersey",
   "geoip.city":"Newark",
   "geoip.zip_code":7102,
   "geoip.time_zone":"America/New_York",
   "geoip.latitude":40.7355,
   "geoip.longitude":-74.1741,
   "geoip.metro_code":501
}
```

Comment: Your documents must be on a single line, no newlines are allowed within them.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 52):

Your resource objects have to be specified on a single line like this

```json
post /test322/type/_bulk
{ "index": {} }
{ "name": "Test1", "data": "This is my test data" }
{ "index": {} }
{ "name": "Test2", "data": "This is my test data2" }
```

Which seems really stupid and unintuitive I know since resources don't have to be on a single line when you create them using PUT or POST for non-bulk operations.

Comment: This saved me a few hours at least.. Thank you ;)

Comment: Also, it expects a line end at the last.

Comment: That doesn't match an actual [example on Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/6.x/bulk_examples.html), but then their documentation is — in places — not optimal.

Comment: This is such a bizarre API, the whole elasticsearch API seems to be written by data scientist rather than programmers... A less intuitive api is hard to find I think...

Comment: @Operator agree about bizarre API - disagree about data scientists

Comment: @Operator This particular API simply supports `ndjson` rather than straight `json` - see https://www.ndjson.org

Answer (score 3):

The following lines' format worked for me very well: **Action**, **metadata**, **resource**

Note: Action should be `CREATE` to add a resource to the dataset and resource should be written inline, **NOT** new line.

```
  POST http://localhost:9200/access_log_index/access_log/_bulk
  { "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "11" } }
  {  "id":11, "tenant_id":682 , ... }
```

Comment: Yup, make sure no \r\n characters are there, I missed removing them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow bulk format to successfully execute this.
it expects the following JSON structure:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

For further reference, see this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-bulk.html

Comment: The essential parts of the answer have been included here here, with link for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting below error when I was manipulating the data set before pushing it to the elastic search(sometimes in serverless environment you can not be certain on order of the events received)

```
 {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_BOOLEAN]"
 }
```

This happens when you modify the sequence of the events that elastic search bulk API expects.
Like, when you use `'doc_as_upsert': true` , the you should have the data in b

```
{
    "update": {
        "_index": "index_name",
        "_id": "id1234"
    }
}
,
{
    "doc_as_upsert": true,
    "doc": {
        "id": "id1234",
        ...otherFields
    }
}
```

You can not skip the update object in this case.

I hope this will be helpful for those who manipulate the dataset before it goes to ES