# Incorrect curl Post syntax for Elasticsearch in Postman

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, postman

I'm a new learned and follow AWS example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-upload-data.html to build my first elasticsearch application.
I'm using Postman for curl command POST to append new document and index as shown here. However it seems the syntax is incorrect highlight by Postman so see if support to correct, thank you!
[image: curl code for Post in postman]

[image: updated]

[image]

Comment: Refer to this Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792309/bulk-api-malformed-action-metadata-line-3-expected-start-object-but-found ,so "_bulk" missed in the end of URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're posting to the `_bulk` URL, then the lines 1 through 6 should be on a single line without newlines. Same for lines 7 and 8. And you need to add a single newline at the end. Like this:

```
{ "index": {"_index": "movies", "_type": "movie", "_id": "2" }}
{ "director": "...", ...}     + add a new line at the end of this line
```

Comment: Hi Val, I followed your suggestion but it seemed not working as below:

Comment: What headers are you adding? You also need the following header: `Content-Type: application/x-ndjson`

Comment: Hi Val, I also updated what has been shown on postman and these headers added, thank you if you can comment more.

Comment: It seems you've added tabs in the actor array (see the red X), cant his be? If yes, you need to remove them.

Comment: Hi Val, no it's not tab and it's the format for next row.

Comment: What does the red X say when you hover over it?

Comment: Simply say "Syntax error", that's why I put title of this question in this way, thank you.

Comment: Paste your document [here](https://www.browserling.com/tools/remove-all-whitespace) and remove all white spaces. Then take the result and try again

Comment: Can you update the question with the raw JSON, please? (not a screenshot, but actual JSON) –