# Bulk API error while indexing data into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk-load, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I want to import some data into elasticsearch using bulk API. this is the mapping I have created using Kibana dev tools:

```
PUT /main-news-test-data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lead": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "agency": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date_created": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "image": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my bulk data:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "1" } }
{
  "content":"\u0641\u0647\u06cc\u0645\u0647 \u062d\u0633\u0646\u200c\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06cc: \u0627\u06af\u0631\u0686\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0647\u06cc\u0627\u0647\u0648\u06cc ",
        "title":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0642\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0641",
        "lead":"\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0647&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;\u0634\u0647\u0631\u06cc -.",
        "agency":"13",
        "date_created":1494518193,
        "url":"http://www.khabaronline.ir/(X(1)S(bud4wg3ebzbxv51mj45iwjtp))/detail/663749/society/urban",
        "image":"uploads/2017/05/11/1589793661.jpg",
        "category":"15",
        "id":"2981643"
}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "2" } }
{ 
....
```

but when I want to post data I receive this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
      }
  "status" : 400
}
```

what is the problem? I used both PowerShell and POST method in Kibana dev tools but I receive the same error in both.

Comment: There should be no new line characters in the JSON documents except at the end of each line

Comment: @Iydal did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @BhavyaGupta yes it worked! thanks

Comment: @Iydal glad I could be of your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The data should be specified in a single line like this:**

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "content":"\u0641\u0647","title":"\u06a9" }
```

Please refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225439/4039431)

Try this below format of bulk JSON. I have tested this bulk API request locally also, and now it's working perfectly fine:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "1" } }
{"content":"\u0641\u0647\u06cc\u0645\u0647 \u062d\u0633\u0646\u200c\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06cc: \u0627\u06af\u0631\u0686\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0647\u06cc\u0627\u0647\u0648\u06cc ", "title":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0642\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0641", "lead":"\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0647&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;\u0634\u0647\u0631\u06cc -.", "agency":"13", "date_created":1494518193, "url":"http://www.khabaronline.ir/(X(1)S(bud4wg3ebzbxv51mj45iwjtp))/detail/663749/society/urban", "image":"uploads/2017/05/11/1589793661.jpg", "category":"15", "id":"2981643"}
```

**Dont forget to add a new line at the end of your content.**